# Disable SSL 3.0 Windows CE Web Server

Tags: ssl, windows-ce

I have web server running on a few devices running a few versions of Windows CE.  One is CE 5.0 and the other is CE 6.0 R3.

I have a tool that can check to see if a server supports TLS and SSL and which versions.  I can see that both of the web servers support TLS 1.0 and SSL 3.0.  I can see from this site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms900411.aspx

that I can disable SSL, but when I do that it also disables TLS 1.0.  Is there a way to turn off SSL 3.0 without turning off TLS?

I also tried what works on Windows Server, but that didn't help either:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this link might help:
[Authentication Services Registry Settings (Windows CE 5.0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms925716.aspx)

Comment: Perfect! It is really close to the server side registry values, just a little different. Also I had to disable SSL 2.0 and PCT 1.0 as well as the SSL 3.0, but I got it! Thanks.